# Is there away to move between workspaces using trackpad?

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to move to other workspaces using trackpad. How can I do that?

Comment: wait for OS X Lion :)

Comment: FYI...I wanted to use BetterTouchTool to use keyboard gestures to switch between my spaces. I have a Windows 7 VM running in Parallels and wanted an easy way to switch between my Mac and Windows. When I ran BTT for the first time, it gave me a message that there are conflicts with Parallels that cause keystroke losses and the developer hasn't been able to solve for this. MagicPrefs works great though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure it's possible with the stock software. [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com) and [Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net) let you define trackpad gestures to do pretty much anything, including mapping them to the key sequences for switching between spaces (by default `Cmd` + arrow keys).

Comment: I use BetterTouchTool to add rotate-two-fingers gestures, one clockwise and the other counter-clockwise, to move from space to space.

Answer (score 7):

The best "vanilla" solution I'm aware of is the following:

Go to *System Preferences > Exposé & Spaces (Exposé tab) > Active Screen Corners* and set one up as "Spaces".

Then when you quickly move your mouse into that corner it will bring up all available workspaces, and you can click the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

[Warp](http://www.ksuther.com/warp/) was designed just for that:

> Warp is a preference pane that allows
> you to use the mouse to switch between
> Spaces rather than using the keyboard.
>
> Warp offers the ability to display a
> live preview of a space when you move
> the mouse to the edge of the screen,
> allowing you to see what you have on
> another space before actually
> switching to it. Clicking the preview
> will then warp you to that space.
> (Enable this feature by checking the
> option "Click screen edge to Warp" in
> Warp's preference pane)